# How to check between two subclasses which one has been called when creating an instance?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to create a "bank account" with its operations. Some of them are:

1. bank addition : class Ajout
2. bank withdrawal : class Retrait

There are the bank balance variable named **solde** and amount named **montant**

The AjoutOuRetrait class is the mother class (means AdditionOrWithdrawal)

Now what I expect in my main class is the following:

```
c1.operation(new Ajout(750, new Date(01,01,2017)));
c1.operation(new Retrait(50, new Date(05,03,2017)));
System.out.println(c1.getSolde());          // result -> 700
```

```
public class AjoutOuRetrait {
    public int montant;
    public Date date;

    public AjoutOuRetrait(int montant, Date d) {
        this.montant = montant;
        this.date = d;
    }
```

```
public class CompteBancaire {
    
    private String id;
    private Banque banque;
    private int solde;  
    
    public CompteBancaire(String id, Banque b) {
        this.id = id;
        this.banque = b;
    }
    
    public void operation(AjoutOuRetrait aor){
        this.solde = aor.montant;
}
```

more the getters and setters that I omitted.

```
public class Retrait extends AjoutOuRetrait {

    public Retrait(int montant, Date d) {
        super(montant, d);
    }
}
```

```
public class Ajout extends AjoutOuRetrait{
        
    public Ajout(int montant, Date d) {
        super(montant, d);
    }
```

I was thinking on a way to differentiate (with conditional statement) which child class I call in argument of **operation()** method , whether it is Retrait (WithDrawal) -- or Ajout(Additional) ++

Comment: Why are addition and withdrawal classes and not methods of a general bank account class?

Comment: to factorize the code I believe, that's the way my professor want us to implement it

Comment: Ah, if it's a requirement from your professor, then I said nothing. Yeah, in that case as it's been said already you can use `instanceof`.

Comment: You could have some common `interface` (`Operation`) that they both `implelement`, which has some method `getAddAmount`, where `Ajout` returns the value, but positive, and `Retrait` returns the negated value.  That said, as a general rule, `int` is not suited to money, `BigDecimal` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check the child type in `operation` like.

```java
public void operation(AjoutOuRetrait aor){
    if(aor instanceof Ajout) {
        this.solde += aor.montant;
    } else if (aor instanceof Retrait) {
        this.solde -= aor.montant;
    }
}
```

or split them

```java
public void operation(Ajout a){
     this.solde += a.montant;
}
public void operation(Retrait r){
     this.solde -= r.montant;
}
```

Also you might get the value used as right operand of your operation like

```java
public class AjoutOuRetrait {
    public int getValue() {
        return this.montant;
    }
}

public class Retrait {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return -this.montant;
    }
}

public void operation(AjoutOrRetrait aor) {
    this.solde += aor.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! what's the better way for you? speaking of memory and time optimization

Comment: You should create a method in `AjoutOrRetrait` like `getValue()` which returns the positive/negative balance and edit `operation(AjoutOrRetrait aor)` to set `this.solde += aor.getValue()`. This is cleaner to me.